# symfony : does database connection really need root user

Tags: php, database, security, symfony

As part of the Symfony set up, I need to perform this task:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Which fails if the user I specify in `app/config/parameters.ini` does not have all privileges. Fair enough, because if you want to update the schema, you would need sufficient privileges to be able to restricted operations such as dropping/ altering tables.

However, what concerns me is that in regular usage of the app, this same database user is also going to be used. I see this as a security vulnerability.

How should I avoid this?

--

Extra info:

[Symfony 2 : multiple and dynamic database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409167/symfony-2-multiple-and-dynamic-database-connection)

This question shows me how I can specify multiple databases for Symfony to use. Would this be of use to me? I don't really need to be able to switch between databases, but just be able to specify that the app, when running uses a restricted user; however, in systems administration time, I need to be able to use root privilege.

Answer (score 2):

In config.yml, use the root user. This will work from the console and from dev mode.

```
    doctrine:
          dbal:
             driver:   %database_driver%
             host:     %database_host%
             port:     %database_port%
             dbname:   %database_name%
             user:     root
             password: pw
             charset:  UTF8
```

In config_prod.yml, add that same block of config but change the username/password. Then, when the app is running in production mode, it will use the less-privileged user.