# Symfony and DoctrineMongoDB : dynamic connections

Tags: mongodb, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have been searching for days for my issue...

Context :
I use Symfony, i have customers, and each customer has its own database. I have a master database with all logins of all my customers, which after the login process, route the user to his own data...

The project use MongoDB for storing data. I am able to connect to a mongodb, store and retrieve data...

So this is my problem : How, with symfony and MongoDB, can i set dynamically the connection to the client database ? because of course, i won't know the database to connect until the user has logged in...

Comment: Which version of symfony do you use?

Comment: I also would like to know it. With ORM there is one solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409167/symfony-2-multiple-and-dynamic-database-connection/9291896#9291896