# Using different database when a user logs in

Tags: session, symfony, database-connection

In Symfony 2.0, I need to change the DB for a particular user until he logs out, but the code is same.

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think it is a great db design if you need to change the database if a user is logged in..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but should not be done the way you described it.

You'll always need connection that will not change: the database that will handle authentication.

Then for each user, you might have a specific database. After login, you should have the account details (database details) you need to connect to the user's database.

Once you have it, use one of the methods described in

Take a look: [Symfony 2 : multiple and dynamic database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409167/symfony-2-multiple-and-dynamic-database-connection)

It should be pretty straightforward.

PS: Instead of a permanent connection, you could also have the users authenticated by another server in an SSO (single sign on) environment - that's advanced topic. The connection details of the user's database should then come from that server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Symfony2, Dynamic DB Connection/Early override of Doctrine Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108732/symfony2-dynamic-db-connection-early-override-of-doctrine-service/15110867#15110867)

It's a slight duplication of the other one, but was specific to using request params, and the answer provides more details in it's wiring of services. Not sure if it's helpful over the other answer, but check it out anyway.