# Switching connection from one database to another fails with Repositories

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I used zulu's `switchDatabase()` method ([Symfony 2 : multiple and dynamic database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409167/symfony-2-multiple-and-dynamic-database-connection)) to switch databases, and it worked well with Symfony 2.1, but since I updated to Symfony 2.3, the data received from Repositories (like `$em->getRepository('...Bundle:...')->find...`) corresponds to the data present in the wrong database. In previous link, bal3no's method doesn't work either. Am I the only one to have this problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: do you change database connections on the fly or just have multiple entity managers configured ?

Comment: I change database connection on the fly: I replace the previous connection by a new one (see link in the question)