# Dynamic database selection using Symfony2 and Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having the following problem:
I have one core database containing Doctrine Entities that keep my login information to other databases. Every client that registers to my application will get his own database. I use subdomains to determain which database must be used. The client database contain other Doctrine Entities, in order to keep the client's data.

To determine the database based on the subdomain, I checked 
[Symfony 2 : multiple and dynamic database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409167/symfony-2-multiple-and-dynamic-database-connection) and http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-dynamic-subdomains . I have tried the asker's solution and the answer's solution.
The given solution works, but only for a part. I created a service to be able to switch between databases in the Controller, but when I create a new Entity, Symfony always wants to execute the CREATE TABLE on the main database.

I'd like Doctrine to divide the tables over the databases. I've also tried Annotations, but I couldn't get it to work. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to separate entities and put them in different databases? Ideally, I should be able to define the database to be used per Entity.

**Additional info:**

Symfony 2.3

Doctrine 2

Answer (score 1):

If you have dynamic database, probably connected into second entity manager (for ex dynamic):

```yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    connections:
      default:
        # default configuration
      dynamic:
        # placeholder used to replace connection information
  orm:
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
      dynamic:
        connection: dynamic
        mappings:
          MyBundle:
            type: annotation
            dir: DynamicEntity # for ext \My\MyBundle\DynamicEntity\Item class
```

Next saving:

```php
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('dynamic');
$em->persist(new \My\MyBundle\DynamicEntity\Item());
$em->flush();
```

You have to rememeber about eneity manager mapping configuration ([more in symfony 2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration)). Without this you will be able to put each entity into both databases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried this solution before, but it does not satisfy my needs. The number of dynamic databases is unknown, so I can not hardcode it into my settings.

Comment: I have a table in central (default) database where I store connection information (host/dbuser/dbname/password). Next I'm using switching database on the fly. "dynamic" entity manager and "dynamic" connection are only placeholders. Database can be different on each request.

Comment: I have managed the same now, only in a different way. Thanks for your help anyway. This question is no longer relevant.