# How do I switch between different databases using an application Symfony 4 with API Platform?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am structuring a Symfony 4 application which is also using API Platform. The problem is that we have a demand that a User will have to connect to its own database. So each time it logs in to a centralized domain (just for access purposes), the application will have to connect him to his own database.

I've done some research, and found out that the closest thing specified in  Symfony 4 docs is the [Multiple Entity Managers and Connections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

The problem here is that although it shows how to create multiple configurations for different database connections, it just specifies how to create them for a specific Entity Manager, or how to get stuff from another Entity Manager inside a Symfony Controller.

In my case, we don't have any Controllers. Instead, there is an API with a couple of services endpoints which connect to the database to manage resources though HTTP requests. Currently, we are using always the default database connection, which gets the configuration from the .env variable.

I know that will have to store this database configuration information in a session (or anything similar) or verify which database is the right one for the given user at each API request. But I'm not so sure what's the best way to deal with this problem.

Also, I thought of creating a listener to the onKernelRequest event, as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151669/symfony-change-database-dynamically)

Any thoughts or ideas how should I proceed with this?

### EDIT

This is the packages/doctrine.yaml file. Everything is configured for default.

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Fst\Entity'
                alias: App
```

And for the .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
```

which is overrided in the .env.local file.

Also, services.yaml has default configuration, with autowiring enabled.

Comment: Please provide some code examples of how you're working with your Symfony app. Such as how you are currently using the default connection.  Normally you use `DependncyInjection` with the `autowire` configuration of your `services.yml` and the specified `entity_manager` from your `packages/doctrine.yml`, which will function the same on the `__construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)` of your service(s) as it does the controller action methods. Alternatively you can manually define which connection you want in your `services.yml` ie `arguments: { $em: '@doctrine.orm.custom_entity_manager' }`

Comment: Which service I have to change in the ```services.yaml``` to change the default entity manager?

And even if I manage to do so, the problem is how do I change that on the fly? There is no ```setDefaultEntityManager``` method or similar to switch between entity managers programatically, right?

Comment: I was referring to an example of how you are issuing queries or interfacing with the ORM in your app. With DI you can specify whatever services and arguments you like to the desired service used when instantiating it, including using [expressions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) The dbal config can also be configured with a [`wrapper_class`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration). Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/29256296/1144627