# Symfony 4 changing databases on the fly

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a blog platform, each blog has it own database.

I need to switch database connection on the fly.

I understand the documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

But i would like to avoid to add everyting in the config file as there are more

than 50 databases.

I ve been trying to adapt this code to symfony 4 but i couldn t make it work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9291896/9726140

Thank you

Comment: >> each blog has it own database, Why?

Comment: @FrankB if each blog is seen as one tenant, why not? It's not only better but even suggested to split this way

Comment: Is other way to do it without set your enviroment variables? and set config with the variable according to your database. But you have to set 50 env variables. Im right?

Comment: Yes, planning more than 50.

Comment: Possbile duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151669/symfony-change-database-dynamically

Comment: @SlimenTN that question is clearly related to symfony version 3 and this is about version 4. there are drastic changes in 4 and the code in that other post will do nothing but drastically fail on version 4. please check more thoroughly before claiming a possible duplicate

Answer (score 4):

I figured out something for my own situation in which each customer had their own subdomain.  I can take advantage of the virtual hosts section of the apache config to add an extra environment variable and use that to set the database name.

In apache:
     
        # ...

```
    SetEnv SUBDOMAIN_NAME "db_name"
</VirtualHost>
```

IN my .env for development (This would go above in apache config for prod) Basically, just strip the database name from the URL

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysql:3306/
```

Finally, in my doctrine.yaml under parameters, I set a default value. This way, we don't blow errors for unconfigured customers and can show a nice clean 'setup necessary' message for tech support:

```
env(SUBDOMAIN_NAME): 'default_customer'
```

and in doctrine.yaml, replace the value for url with

```
url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%%env(resolve:SUBDOMAIN_NAME)%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try that from Controller:

```
$sql = "USE dbname";
$stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your reply. But the getConnection() method is not found.

Comment: Hi, i am using symfony 3.4 and that method works for me.

Comment: Symfony 4 had some breaking changes that make some stuff non existent now or just not work.