# Symfony: change database dynamically

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

let's say I have 3 databases:

- prefix_db1
- prefix_db2
- prefix_db3

And I want to connect to them dynamically from the url like this    `http://localhost/my-project/web/app_dev.php/db1/books` so I know which database to    conenct to from the url (in this case `prefix_db1`)
 
And basically the idea was to prepare a listener that will be fired with each **http request**, get the database name from the url and then override doctrin's params, something like this:
Within **services.yml**:

```
dynamic_connection:
        class: AppBundle\service\DynamicDBConnector
        arguments:  ['@request_stack']
        calls:
            - [ setDoctrineConnection, ['@doctrine.dbal.default_connection'] ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

My listener:

```
<?php    
namespace AppBundle\service;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Exception;

class DynamicDBConnector
{
    /**
     * @var Connection
     */
    private $connection;

    /*
     * @var Request
     */
    private $request;


    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

    }

    /**
     * Sets the DB Name prefix to use when selecting the database to connect to
     *
     * @param  Connection       $connection
     * @return DynamicDBConnector $this
     */
    public function setDoctrineConnection(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        return $this;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
        if ($this->request->attributes->has('_company')) {

            $connection = $this->connection;
            $params     = $this->connection->getParams();

            $companyName = $this->request->get('_company');
            // I did the concatenation here because in paramaters.yml I just put the prefix (database_name: prefix_) so after the concatenation I get the whole database name "prefix_db1"
            $params['dbname'] = $params['dbname'] . $companyName;

            // Set up the parameters for the parent
            $connection->__construct(
                $params,
                $connection->getDriver(),
                $connection->getConfiguration(),
                $connection->getEventManager()
            );

            try {
                $connection->connect();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // log and handle exception
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now this worked very well I have tested it using a simple list of books and each time I change the url I get the list related to each database:

```
http://localhost/my-project/web/app_dev.php/db1/books // I get books of database prefix_db1

http://localhost/my-project/web/app_dev.php/db2/books // I get books of database prefix_db2
```

**Now let's get to the problem shall we :)**:
The problem now is that when I secure my project with authentication system and try to login (of course each database has `user` table) using this url `http://localhost/my-project/web/app_dev.php/db1/login`
I get this exception :

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Base 'prefix_' unknown
```

As you can see symfony tried to login the user using the `database_name` declared in **parameters.yml** which means that the `security_checker` of symfony has been fired before my listener and before overriding Doctrine's `params`.
**My question**:
Is there any way to fire my listener before any other http request listener ? or maybe an alternative solution to make sure that any request to database must be with the right database name.
Sorry for the long post.
**EDIT:**
From the official documentation of symfony:
https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

> The other optional tag attribute is called  priority, which defaults
>   to 0 and it controls the order in which listeners are executed (**the
>   highest the priority, the earlier a listener is executed**). This is
>   useful when you need to guarantee that one listener is executed before
>   another. The priorities of the internal Symfony listeners usually
>   range from -255 to 255 but your own listeners can use any positive or
>   negative integer.

I set the priority of my listener to **10000**:

```
tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 10000 }
```

But the problem persist, still can't fire my listener before symfony!

Comment: @goto each database has it's own users so I need to know which one before connecting to it

Comment: What does your database have in common? you can create 3 separate instance of your app, one of each database instead. (Sry I can't help you for the prefix problem)

Comment: they are all the same, in fact in the future will be more than 3 database they will be created dynamically using doctrine commands `doctrine:database:create` `doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2, Dynamic DB Connection/Early override of Doctrine Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108732/symfony2-dynamic-db-connection-early-override-of-doctrine-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great solution but if you want get the parameter `_company` from the URL you can retrieve the container inside the constructor through the `EventManager` object passed in parameters and get the current request from it, in fact the container is injected into `ContainerAwareEventManager` the sub class of `EventManager`

```
class DynamicDBConnector extends Connection
{
    public function __construct($params, $driver, $config, $eventManager)
    {
        if(!$this->isConnected()){
            // Create default config and event manager if none given (case in command line)
            if (!$config) {
                $config = new Configuration();
            }
            if (!$eventManager) {
                $eventManager = new EventManager();
            }

            $refEventManager = new \ReflectionObject($eventManager);
            $refContainer = $refEventManager->getProperty('container');
            $refContainer->setAccessible('public'); //We have to change it for a moment

            /*
             * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
             */
            $conrainer = $refContainer->getValue($eventManager);

            /*
             * @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
             */
            $request = $conrainer->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

            if ($request != null && $request->attributes->has('_company')) {
                $params['dbname'] .= $request->attributes->get('_company');
            }

            $refContainer->setAccessible('private'); //We put in private again
            parent::__construct($params, $driver, $config, $eventManager);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution
The idea is tochange the default `Connection` class that symfony uses to create a database connection:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                wrapper_class: AppBundle\Doctrine\DynamicConnection
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
```

After that we can change the given params in the constructor:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

class DynamicConnection extends Connection
{
    public function __construct(array $params, Driver $driver, $config, $eventManager)
    {
        $params['dbname'] = 'teqsdqsdqst';
        parent::__construct($params, $driver, $config, $eventManager);
    }
}
```

Now we just need to get the parameter from the url and set inside `$params['dbname']`.
In this way we make sure that symfony will always use this class to create the connection and we no longer need to fire listeners with **http requestes**

Comment: How do you get parameters from the constructor method? I've tried to use RequestStack but gives me null.

Comment: @Giovani please check the marked answer maybe it will help because I'm following it and it's working fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using doctrine.dbal.connection_factory as proposed by TvC in [Symfony2, Dynamic DB Connection/Early override of Doctrine Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108732/symfony2-dynamic-db-connection-early-override-of-doctrine-service).
I was able to it in Symfony 6:

```
#services.yaml
App\Routing\DBAL\DatabaseConnectionFactory:
        decorates: doctrine.dbal.connection_factory
        arguments:       
            $requestStack: '@request_stack'
            

#DatabaseConnectionFactory.php
namespace App\Routing\DBAL;

use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory;

class DatabaseConnectionFactory extends ConnectionFactory
{
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct( $requestStack )
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;    
    }

    public function createConnection(
        array $params,
        Configuration $config = null,
        EventManager $eventManager = null,
        array $mappingTypes = []
    )
    {
       $uri = null;
       $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

       if( $request ) {
            $uri = $request->getUri();
       }

       if( $uri && str_contains($uri, 'c/lmh/pathology') ) {
            //here logic to get dbname
            $dbName = 'Tenant2';
            $params['dbname'] = $dbName;
        } else {
            //don't change default dbname
        }
        return parent::createConnection($params, $config, $eventManager, $mappingTypes);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

you should add the database name in your config.yml like this :

```
 orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
#        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
#        auto_mapping: true
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    DataMiningBundle: ~
                    AppBundle: ~
                    UserBundle: ~

            your_second_db:
                connection: your_second_db (decalared in parameters.yml)
                mappings:
                    yourBundle: ~
```

and call it from your controller :

```
 $em = $doctrine->getConnection('your_second_db');
```

Comment: No I can't because the databases will be created dynamically from another form, they are not predefined :)

Comment: i dont think that @SlimenTN didn't know this mr haythem